# Stop builtin(?) repos. Configure RHEL 8 to use only local repos

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I downloaded a DVD image of RHEL 8 and I want to use only the packages therein.  That image already contains indexed BaseOS and AppStream repos, so I just have mount it and put a `local.repo` file with `baseurl=file:///whatever` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.  Until that part, I know what to do.

Now, I want to delete any reference to other repos that might exist or might have existed in my machine.  So I wiped `/etc/yum.repos.d/` off any other `.repo` file and wiped the `/var/cache/dnf/`.  However, when I do a `$ yum info` or `$ yum repolist`, somehow, even without internet connection, `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` comes back from the dead and `/var/cache/dnf/` gets repopulated.  And I get `curl` errors because I don't have that machine connected to the internet.

I want `yum` to have to deal only with the repos I configured in `local.repo`.  How do I do that?

I'm coming from [sudo yum repolist show repo not in /etc/yum.repo.d](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222750/sudo-yum-repolist-show-repo-not-in-etc-yum-repo-d) and [Remove yum repo using yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53627/remove-yum-repo-using-yum) so I already tried the `$ dnf config-manager --disablerepo`, `--nopluggins` and other stuff in those answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not delete other repo files. Just make sure that each entry `/etc/yum.repos.d/*`, for which you do not want to be used any more, has a line `enabled=0`. Then you add entries as you already did. My example of such repo file looks like this:

```
[c8-disk-BaseOS]
name=CentOS-BaseOS- - Media
baseurl=file:///CentOS/BaseOS
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

[c8-media-AppStream]
name=CentOS-AppStream- - Media
baseurl=file:///CentOS/AppStream
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
```

And here is an example of disabled default entry:

```
# CentOS-AppStream.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[AppStream]
name=CentOS-$releasever - AppStream
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=AppStream&infra=$infra
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
```

I do that very often, because I have CentOS computers in an isolated environment without internet access. In that way, I keep a copy of installation media on disk, and I can install whatever is provided with the that media.

Answer (score 0):

`redhat.repo` is managed by `subscription-manager`. If you do not want to be subscribed run `subscription-manager remove` and `subscription-manager unregister`.